# How to define an equivariant Kasparov's KK-theory map?

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, index-theory, kk-theory

I'm looking for some references about how to construct an equivariant [Kasparov's KK-theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/KK-theory) map $$ \psi \ : \ KK^{G_{1}} ( A,B ) \to KK^{G_{2}} ( C,D ) $$, where, $ G_1 $ and $ G_2 $ are two distinct topological groups, or two distinct locally compact groups, and $ A $ and $B$ ( resp. $ C $ and $ D $ ) are $ G_1 $ - $ C^* $ - algebras ( resp. $ G_2 $ - $ C^* $ - algebras ) ? How to define it precisely in a more general context?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this treated in [Claude Schochet's 1992 paper "On Equivariant Kasparov Theory and Spanier-Whitehead Duality"](https://www.academia.edu/10690447/On_equivariant_Kasparov_theory_and_Spanier_Whitehead_duality)? Also, if you want more references, I'd recommend [using Google Scholar to see who cites this paper](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?cites=4972653043000153702&as_sdt=5,36&sciodt=0,36&hl=en). I note that this led me to a 2011 paper by Uuye about restriction maps (like your situation when $G_2$ is a subgroup of $G_1$).

EDIT: In the light of day, I remembered a better reference. The book [K-Theory for Operator Algebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K-Theory+for+Operator+Algebras) by Bruce Blackadar answers this question in Section 20.5, which begins with the line "We now consider to what extent $KK_G$ is functorial in $G$." This book seems to be the canonical reference for equivariant $KK$-theory.

Comment: Thank you. But, unfortunately not, this is not treated in the two links that you mentionned. Can you help me to find a book which talk widely about this subject ? Thank you.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be well-defined. You are just asking how to construct a map between two very abstract things that have nothing in common ($KK_{G_1}(A,B)$ and $KK_{G_2}(C,D)$). Without more assumptions, the only natural map is the zero map. The answer given here addresses the very natural question of "what happens if there is some natural relationship between $G_1$ and $G_2$ which induces a relationship between $A$ and $C$, and $B$ and $D$?". If you want a different answer, you need to be much more specific about what your question is.